# How to access package from bin folder from src folder

Tags: java, package, javaimports

So I have a folder structure as below

```
mainFolder\
    bin\
        file1.class,file2.class,file3.class,file4.class //under package named classes
    src\
        socialmedia\
            file5.java,file6.java,file7.java //under package named socialmedia
        PlatformTestApp
```

How can I import the package inside the bin folder from the socialmedia subfolder inside the src folder

I'm aware a question like this has almost certainly been answered before but I can't for the life for me find what I need

Comment: Are you trying to use code from compiled java code?  A bin folder should have .class files and not .java files

Comment: @Nexevis yes sorry forgot to specify file types, updated the post now

Comment: Where is file1.java, file2.java? If the answer is that they are in another project then you need to make a jar from that project, add the jar to this project (usually in lib) and add the jar to the classpath. Or you could use maven/gradle dependencies.

Comment: @JohnWilliams file1.java etc. don't exist, that's just how I named the files. So how can I access the class files from within file6.java in the socialmedia package

Answer (score 1):

Any files on the classpath, which /bin certainly is, can be accessed like this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("file1.class");
```

I have to ask - what problem are you solving that includes this very unusual requirement?

Comment: Genuinely just how the coursework structured the directories and not allowed to change that